# No reason for menu bar to not work?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jmenubar, jpanelmenu

In this piece of code, I have absolutely no idea why my Menu bar doesn't work, may seem trivial and stupid to everyone here, but I'll really appreciate if someone can tell me why my Menu bar is not showing..

[Bonus] Also, I have no idea why  "add(Canvas);" doesn't work, but I managed to find a solution to that with some research anyways, but if possible an explanation for that would be useful.

```
package drawer;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

import java.util.*;

public class Drawer {
public static void main(String[] args) {

        JMenuBar MenuBar; // My Menu code, which doesn't work..
        MenuBar = new JMenuBar();

        JMenu FileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        MenuBar.add(FileMenu);

        JMenuItem FileSaveMenu = new JMenuItem("Save");
        FileMenu.add(FileSaveMenu);


        JMenuItem FileLoadMenu = new JMenuItem("Load");
        FileMenu.add(FileLoadMenu);
        JMenuItem FileExitMenu = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        FileMenu.add(FileExitMenu);


        JMenu HelpMenu = new JMenu("Help");  
        JMenuItem FileAboutMenu = new JMenuItem("About");
        HelpMenu.add(FileAboutMenu); 

        JFrame MainWindow = new JFrame(); 
        FlowLayout layoutObj = new FlowLayout();
        MainWindow.setLayout(layoutObj);
        MainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        MainWindow.setSize(1600, 900); 
        MainWindow.setVisible(true);      


        JPanel ControlPanel = new JPanel();
        ControlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING));     
        ControlPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(), "Control Panel"));
        ControlPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 750));              
        MainWindow.getContentPane().add(ControlPanel);

        JPanel Canvas = new JPanel();
        Canvas.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER)); 
        Canvas.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(), "Canvas")); 
        Canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1300, 750)); 
        MainWindow.getContentPane().add(Canvas); // Where "add(Canvas);" doesn't work and this was the solution after researching..  

        JPanel MessageArea = new JPanel();
        MessageArea.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));     
        MessageArea.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(), "Messages"));
        MessageArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1500, 100));
        MainWindow.getContentPane().add(MessageArea);
    }

}
```

Comment: add(Canvas) when Canvas was a `Canvas` didn't work because it is a *heavyweight* awt component, rather than a lightweight swing component. In summary, you shouldn't use classes that extend `Component` in java.awt , except `Container`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add

```
MainWindow.setJMenuBar(MenuBar);
```

at the end

Comment: Ima worship you for the next 24 hours I swear aha.. I hate the fact that the hardest of problems can take beginners hours but really its a couple of seconds to fix. Cheers bud !

Comment: @James if you want to be a software developer, you're going to have to learn to love these kinds of challenges. For me, there came a point where I had no more tolerance for it :-)

Comment: I love overcoming the challenge, not the challenge itself I guess :')
Thanks again !